# I am trying to set up my sprite position on the y-axis, but for some reason it keeps the 0 location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 targetPos;
    public float Xincrement;

    public float speed;
    public float maxWidth;
    public float minWidth;

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x < maxWidth)
        {
            targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + Xincrement, transform.position.y);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x > minWidth)
        {
            targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x - Xincrement, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that's related, but shouldn't a `Vector3` be created with a Z component?

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`